Using Application Insights with Serilog, when sending traces trying to set "cloud_RoleName" but the property stays empty?
So I'm trying to figure out why my "cloud_RoleName" stays empty when sending the trace log with Serilog to Application Insights.
I'm using the following resources/references, but they don't seem to work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling?tabs=dotnetcore%2Cjavascriptwebsdkloaderscript#add-a-cloud-role-name
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics
https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2020/02/05/setting-cloud-role-name-in-application-insights.aspx
How to set the cloud_roleName for Application Insights for .NET Core?
And here's my code:
Program.cs:
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
{
    config.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);
    config.Enrich.With(new CustomEnricher(configuration));
});

Startup.cs (actually a separate file being called in Startup):
public static class InstrumentationStartup
{
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureInstrumentation(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
    {
        var initializer = new InstrumentationInitializer(configuration);
        var options = initializer.CreateServiceOptions();

        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, WebTelemetryInitializer>();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<WebTelemetryFilter>();

        logger.LogInformation($"Application Insights was initialized with Instrumentation Key '{options.InstrumentationKey}'");
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options);

        return services;
    }
}

InstrumentationInitializer:
public class InstrumentationInitializer
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public InstrumentationInitializer(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions CreateServiceOptions()
    {
        var instrumentationKey = _configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];

        var options = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
        {
            InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey,
            
        };

#if DEBUG
        options.DeveloperMode = true;
        options.EnableDebugLogger = true;
#endif

        return options;
    }
}

WebTelemetryInitializer:
public class WebTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly string _code;
    private string _version;

    public WebTelemetryInitializer(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var code = configuration["ApplicationInsights:Code"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)) _code = code;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (_version == null) _version = typeof(WebTelemetryInitializer).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();

        var context = telemetry.Context;

        context.Cloud.RoleName = "Web";
        context.Component.Version = _version;

        context.GlobalProperties["cloud_RoleName"] = "EverybodyGetsACloudRoleName";

        if (telemetry is ISupportProperties supported)
        {
            supported.Properties["Code"] = _code;
            supported.Properties["Product"] = "CustomProduct";
        }
    }
}

WebTelemetryFilter:
public class WebTelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor 
{
    ...
    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {            
        if (DiscardItem(item)) return;

        item.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "MyCloudRoleNameTest";

        _next.Process(item);
    }
    ...
}

CustomEnricher:
public class CustomEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
   private readonly string _code;
   private string _version;

   public CustomEnricher(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       var code = configuration["ApplicationInsights:Code"];
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)) _code = code;
   }

   public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
   {
       if (_version == null) _version = typeof(WebTelemetryInitializer).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();

       var product = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("Product", "CustomProduct");
       logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(product);

       var code = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("CustomCode", _code);
       logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(code);

       var version = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("version", _version); 
       logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(version);

       // This is added under CustomDimensions(not what I want!)
       var roleName = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("cloud_RoleName", "Web");
       logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(roleName);

       logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("cloud_RoleName", new ScalarValue("This is my new cloud_RoleName!")));
   }
}

As you can see, I'm trying to set the "Telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName" to "Web", I'm trying to change the "Telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties" to something else, trying to add it to the LogEvent properties (but that adds it to CustomDimensions), but nothing seems to work... My column "cloud_RoleName" in Azure Insights is still empty.
It's seemingly so simple, looking at the resources/references, but it doesn't come through for me in ApplicationInsights. As a "CustomDimension" it does add, but I want it separately of course in the default property.
Does anyone know what could be wrong?


Using Application Insights with Serilog, when sending traces trying to set "cloud_RoleName" but the property stays empty?

The issue is with integration of Serilog and Telemetry Cilent  according to Document. Even I have got empty name when used serilog:

But in Program.cs, I have used  rith.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RithwikCloudInitializer>() as  below:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

var rith = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
rith.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RithwikCloudInitializer>();
rith.Services.AddRazorPages();
rith.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
---------
---------
app.Run();

Cloud Name Initializer :
public class RithwikCloudInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry ri_tcl)
    {
        ri_tcl.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "RithwikCloud";
    }
}

Output:

